# datagrid: Disable sort on some columns

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am aware I can prevent the user from clicking on ANY of the columns in a Flex datagrid by using

```
sortableColumns=false;
```

But I would like only some columns to allow sorting. How would I go about achieving this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GridColumn` has property `sortable`. So you can set `DataGrid`'s property `sortableColumns` to `true` and prohibit sorting on certain columns by setting their property `sortable` to `false`.

Comment: How could I have missed that. Thanks that does work perfectly!